# Powershell code to list installed Windows software misbehaves when called as SYSTEM user

Tags: windows, powershell, com

I have a simple powershell snippet to list installed Windows software and versions:

```
$msi = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$msi.GetType().InvokeMember('ProductsEx', 'GetProperty', $null, $msi, ('', 's-1-1-0', 7)) | select @{ name='name'; expression={$_.GetType().InvokeMember('InstallProperty', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, ('ProductName')) } }, @{ name='version'; expression={$_.GetType().InvokeMember('InstallProperty', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, ('VersionString'))} }
```

When run as an ordinary user, this is the result:-

```
PS C:\Users\fmwebroot> c:\test.ps1

name                                               version
----                                               -------
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64... 9.0.21022
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable ... 10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x86 Redistributable ... 10.0.40219
aws-cfn-bootstrap                                  1.4.5
EC2ConfigService                                   3.5.228.0
AWS Tools for Windows                              3.7.543.0
Microsoft Web Deploy 3.5                           3.1237.1764
IIS Advanced Logging 1.0                           1.0.0625.10
Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0               5.0.50430.0
Mercurial 3.1.1 (x64)                              3.1.1
ConEmu 140814.x64                                  11.140.8140
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86... 9.0.21022
Opsview NSClient++ Windows Agent (x64)             0.3.9.336
New Relic Server Monitor                           3.3.2.0
7-Zip 9.20 (x64 edition)                           9.20.00.0
New Relic .NET Agent (64-bit)                      3.10.43.0
Python 3.4.1 (64-bit)                              3.4.1150
```

When run as a system user, the Python package's name is always missing. I see this on multiple machines. The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.

```
PS C:\Users\fmwebroot> psexec -s cmd /c "echo . | powershell -File c:\test.ps1"

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com



name                                    version
----                                    -------
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistribu... 9.0.21022
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redis... 10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x86 Redis... 10.0.40219
aws-cfn-bootstrap                       1.4.5
EC2ConfigService                        3.5.228.0
AWS Tools for Windows                   3.7.543.0
Microsoft Web Deploy 3.5                3.1237.1764
IIS Advanced Logging 1.0                1.0.0625.10
Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0    5.0.50430.0
Mercurial 3.1.1 (x64)                   3.1.1
ConEmu 140814.x64                       11.140.8140
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistribu... 9.0.21022
Opsview NSClient++ Windows Agent (x64)  0.3.9.336
New Relic Server Monitor                3.3.2.0
7-Zip 9.20 (x64 edition)                9.20.00.0
New Relic .NET Agent (64-bit)           3.10.43.0
                                        3.4.1150


cmd exited on IP-0A63009C with error code 0.
PS C:\Users\fmwebroot>
```

I noticed this issue because this Powershell code is spawned by a running process to list installed software, and I couldn't work out why it kept thinking that Python was not installed. I managed to create this simple demo of the problem by analysing what was actually happening under the hood.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and how I could fix it?

Comment: Pure guess: Python is installed on a per-user basis and not system wide

Comment: try using  `gwmi Win32_Product -ComputerName mycomputername | select name, version`